# OS X Color Picker: Removing a Colour Swatch

Tags: macos, color

I am running OS X El Capitan, and any solutions I have found are out of date.

I can add a colour to my swatch drawer by dragging it. However, how do I remove a colour?

All the articles I have read suggest dragging an adjacent white cell onto the colour, but the empty cells are no longer white and and attempting to drag an empty cell does nothing.

Thanks

Comment: How about using the eye-drop tool to select the background color of an "empty" swatch (`#ECECEC`), and then dragging and replacing the colors you'd like to delete? They will appear "empty" and you can always overwrite them. I agree that there definitely is not an intuitive way to do this.

Answer (score 20):

You can actually just drag & drop them to your desktop trashcan.

This works in High Sierra, I'm not sure if it does for previous versions.

Comment: Works for Mojave 10.14.5. as well

Comment: Confirming this also works for Big Sur (I'm on 11.0.1).

Comment: Clicking a swatch and pressing delete also works, but this one is better because you don't have to click the swatch which has the potential downside of applying the swatch to a selected object. It's insane that you don't just drag it outside the swatch panel like you would remove an app from the Dock or at least right click it to delete, but whatever, it is what it is.

Comment: This answer was edited as if I am not sure about previous versions.. I never said this, stop doing that

Answer (score 13):

Just discovered today, March 2018, you can now just select the color chip (soft online indicates it's selected) and use "delete" key.

Comment: Why is this answer down-voted? I just verified, running 10.13.4 and indeed selecting a swatch and hitting the keyboard "Delete" key clears the swatch.

Comment: @JamesKachan Agreed.

Comment: When I could get the blue highlight around the swatch, this worked - I was able to press the delete key to delete the swatch. In some cases, I could not get the highlight to appear around the swatch. In those cases, dragging the swatch to the trash in the dock worked. High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: @ChristianLong Moving the swatch to the trash worked for me!

Comment: No longer working in 10.15 Catalina.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Terminal Inspector Colors]

The Colors dialog can be used to modify the swatch selection.  Specifically, selecting and using the delete key, or by dragging to the trash can. You can also use this to rearrange swatches

High Sierra 10.13.4 Beta

Comment: This doesn't work on macOS Sierra as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

A good way of doing this is editing the `~/Library/Colors/NSColorPanelSwatches.plist` file. Open this file in a plist editor or in Xcode, and remove all the `Item 1`, `Item 2` and so on entries, leaving `Item 0` as it is.

The `.plist` should end up looking like this:

[image: img]

Restart the app/color picker and the color swatches should be removed

Answer (score 2):

This does not apply to your case with El Capitan (still don't know how to easily delete a color in that OS). But things have changed with High Sierra (untested in Sierra). Simply drag a swatch to the trash to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag a defined swatch onto another defined one. One gets overwritten, the other blank again. Kind like playing "musical chairs" …Works even in El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Using the eye dropper actually does work. What is interesting is that once you drag it to a swatch that swatch becomes "blank" you can continue to drag that to other swatches and "blank" those out, but if you go back to a swatch you blanked out, that one is no longer draggable. The only draggable "blank" swatch is the last one you "blanked" out.

Answer (score 0):

Just **drag** the saved color to the **Trash** on the dock!!!

Comment: Works as of 10.15.4.

Comment: This is the same answer as [Jonas Praem’s](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322811/244618)

Answer (score 0):

After searching and testing, I've found two ways to remove your color swatch, TV under MacOS Catalina.

1. drag the color swatch to the trashcan in the dock
2. click the color swatch your want to remove and press cmd+delete on the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this

1) Go to your desktop

2) Click control+click on the trackpad

3) Go to "change the desktop background"

4) In the options choose "fit the picture to the screen"

5) You will see the margin color in the right side and click on it

6) Now the color plate will open and you can click on them and click command + delete

Answer (score 0):

High Sierra: Just <kbd>alt</kbd> + "click" the swatch to select, then press <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

In some other application, you can also activate apple color picker. But alt click to select may not work. What you need to do is to drop one new swatch on to an existing one and hold!!! (do not let go your drag ) and wait until you see blue selection outline emerge, then you can delete the outlined one with the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

PS. don't be upset if after drag & waiting no blue outline appears automatically.Click in to the swatch will retrieve the selection outline.